# Combining Animoji and AVSpeechSynthesizer with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I'm attempting to mix and match Animoji and the AVSpeechSynthesizer so that I could call a list of quotes and have an Animoji visually present and available and speaking them.

I'm not sure if this is possible with Swift / Swift Playgrounds, but I'd welcome any suggestions as to how to do this. I've seen some tutorials out there for using Swift to create custom Animoji faces, but I'm not entirely sure how to combine these two things together.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Swift Playground isn't the best place to test this out. That being said, what have you tried so far, what does your code look like?

Comment: i only have the speechsynthesizer part going right now. @ZGski.. while i do have an animoji or two on iOS, I'm not sure how to export them to macOS / Xcode. I could probably easily go from Swift Playgrounds to regular Swift, but have yet to find anything related to Animoji + speech sync.